# Unable to implement Search() using vuex

Tags: vue.js, search, vuejs2, filtering

I want to see the search result when I type something in search if the search is null then I want to see all the items.
but search method is called and then state.inventory is not updating with all the items

[image: my search is not working]

```
navbar.vue
<div class="input-field right">
          <input @keyup="search" id="search" type="search" required v-model="keyword">
          <label class="label-icon" for="search">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
          </label>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      keyword: "",


    };
  },
methods: {
    search()
    {
      if(this.keyword != "")
        this.$store.dispatch("addToSearch", this.keyword);

    },
```

```
inventory.vue
<div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index" class="col s12 m4">

export default {
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.getInventory;
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchAllItem();
  },
  methods: {
        fetchAllItem() {
      axios.get("https://ekart-4c0aa.firebaseio.com/0/data.json")
      .then(response => {            
            this.items=response.data;
            console.log(this.items);
        this.$store.commit("setInventory", response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

```
store.js

mutations:{
addToSearch(state,payload){
                if(payload != ""){                    
                state.inventory= state.inventory.filter(item => {
                return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(payload.toLowerCase());
              });

        }  } }
actions: {
        addToSearch(context,payload){
            context.commit('addToSearch',payload)
        },
```

Expected result in 3 stages:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont need to mutate dataset in store, just keep search word there. Then, when you call store getter, check in it that result of filtering dataset is empty, if so, retrun full dataset. Also, use mapGetters in your components for clearer code.